# Looking for assistance getting rpy2 version 3.x to work with Windows

Tags: windows, rpy2

rpy2 version 3.x no longer works on windows (https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/570/ensure-rpy2-31x-is-working-on-windows). I recently contacted the author of rpy2 and got a list of issues that need to be addressed in order to resolve this issue, but it is outside my area of expertise, so wondering if anyone is interested in working on this. It's got me in a bind cause I can't get my environments to solve.

From the rpy2 author:

There are 2-3 problems to figure out to have an initial support of Windows back:

- figure out why the R.dll cannot be loaded with cffi's dlopen (ABI mode)

or

- work out how to build rpy2 with compilation (API mode)

and

- finalize the initialization of for windows (this is all Python code, calling the R C-API through cffi)

You could start by

- getting the master branch on github
- run python setup.py install on your windows machine
- import rpy2.rinterface and try make the loading of the R.dll work...

Comment: The issue tracker for the rpy2 project might be a better place to track this.

Comment: Yup just realizing this now, thanks. I am a newbie.